# CDF depending on the bandwidth used in kernel density estimation?

Tags: r, kernel, bandwidth, kernel-density, cumulative-sum

I do not know exactly why the cdf has different values when I change the bandwidth in the kernel density estimation. In the code below, I generate random numbers from a gaussian distribution and estimate the kernel density of the data in selecting different bandwidths (h). When I integrate the pdf I get different values more or less distant from 1. So, it seems that the CDF depends on the bandwidth used in the kernel density estimation. Yet, I beleived that the factor 1/nh in kernel desnity estimation ensures that the pdf integrates to 1. if the bandwidth is the issue, how can I determine it to ensure that the resulting pdf integrates to 1?

```
g<-1
n<-1000
set.seed(g)
df <- data.frame(x=sort(rnorm(n,0,1))) 

library(functional)

gaussianKernel <- function(u) exp(-u^2/2)/(2*pi)^.5

densityFunction <- function(x, df, ker, h){
    difference = t(t(df) - x)/h
    W = sum(apply(difference, 1, ker)) / (nrow(df)*h)
}

myDensityFunction <- Curry(densityFunction, df=df, ker=gaussianKernel, h=2)

vect<-vector()
for (i in 1:length(df$x)){
f<-myDensityFunction(df$x[i])
vect<-c(vect,f)
}

f <- approxfun(df$x, vect, yleft = 0, yright = 0)
integrate(f, -Inf, Inf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the effect of bandwidth.  As the bandwidth increases the bias of the estimator increases while the variance decreases.  There are some rules of thumb to calculate the bandwidth.  I give one below, and you can see that with proper bandwidth, the estimated density curve approaches the exact normal.  Vectorizing your functions will give you a speedup

```
kernel <- function(u) exp(-u^2/2) / (2*pi)^.5
dens <- Vectorize(function(x, df, ker, h) {
    1/(h*nrow(df)) * sum(ker((df-x)/h))
}, vec="x")

b <- 1.06*(min(1, IQR(df$x)/1.34))*n^(-1/5)  # bandwidth rule-of-thumb
vect <- dens(df$x, df=df, kernel, b)
f <- approxfun(df$x, vect, yleft=0, yright=0)
integrate(f, -Inf, Inf)
# 0.9991092 with absolute error < 0.00012

nvals <- dnorm(df$x)
plot(df$x, nvals)
points(df$x, vect, col="azure3")
```

[image]

Comment: 6pool, thank you very much. What I understand is that I have to select a bandwidth such as the CDF can integrate to 1 (is the only constraint to be satisfied?). So, I also can optimize the bandwidwth under this constraint. Am I correct?